# cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature - but it is defined

Tags: typescript

I have problem with a 'new' constructor in an interface definition:

```
interface DateOnlyStatic {
    new: (y: number, m: number, d: number) => DateOnly;
    today: () => DateOnly;
    fromDate(d: DateOnly): DateOnly;
    fromISOString(s: string): DateOnly;
    fromBaseDateTime(a: any): any;
    areEqual(d1: DateOnly, d2: DateOnly): boolean;
    comparer(d1: DateOnly, d2: DateOnly): boolean;
}


interface DateOnly extends Date {
    monday: () => DateOnly;
    addDays: (i: number) => DateOnly;
    addMonths: (i: number) => DateOnly;
    getTotalDays: () => number;

}

declare var DateOnly: DateOnlyStatic;


declare var g = new DateOnly(2001, 1, 1);
```

in the last line, the compiler complains `cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`. Why? Did not I declare exactly that in  line 2?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of your constructor signature is wrong, you define a field named new which is a function. This is how constructor signature should look:

```
interface DateOnlyStatic {
    new (y: number, m: number, d: number) : DateOnly;
}
```

Comment: But how I define the contructor function then? `var DateOnly = function (year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}` doesnot work

Comment: @Ferenjito Why not just derive directly from `Date` as that is what you seem to want anyway ?http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20DateOnly%20extends%20Date%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(y%3A%20number%2C%20m%3A%20number%2C%20d%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09super(y%2C%20m%2C%20d)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09static%20today()%20%3A%20DateOnly%20%7B%20return%20null%3B%7D%0D%0A%09addDays(i%3A%20number)%20%3A%20DateOnly%20%7B%20return%20null%3B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20g%20%3D%20new%20DateOnly(2001%2C%201%2C%201)%3B%0D%0Ag.addDays(10)%3B%0D%0ADateOnly.today()%3B

Comment: I am working with legacy code here which I should not change, and additionally,  I would like to understand the general approach here.

Comment: The constructor function should look like: `var DateOnly = function (year, month, day) { doSomething() }`